# Trying to find a simple way to do upload only modified files through FTP

Tags: command-line, ftp

Need to find a way to upload files to my server through FTP. But only the ones that have been modified. 
Is there a simple way of doing that? 
Command line ftp client or script is preferred. 
Thanks, Jonas.

Comment: What's the OS/platform on which the script will run?

Answer (score 7):

The most reliable way would be to make md5 hashes of all the local files you care about and store it in a file.  So the file will contain a list of filenames and their md5 hashes.  Store that file on your ftp server.  When you want to update the files on your ftp server, download the file containing the list, compare that against all your local files, and upload the files that have changed (or are new).  That way you don't have to worry about archive bits, modified date, or looking at file sizes, the use of which can never be 100% reliable.

Using file sizes isn't reliable for the obvious reason - a file could change but have the same size.  I'm not a fan of using the archive bit or modified date because either of those could be confused if you backup or restore your local directory with another backup program.

Answer (score 5):

git-ftp works really nice:

```
apt-get install git-ftp
```

in the application folder:

```
git config git.ftp.xxxx.url ftpservice.server.com/root/dir/for/ftp
git config git.ftp.xxxx.user myUsername
git config git.ftp.xxxx.password myPassword
```

following only if target is up-to-date by other ftp client (it changes ftpservice.server.com/root/dir/for/ftp/git-ftp.log to current commit)

```
git ftp catchup --scope xxxx
```

//editing sources//

```
git commit -m "new version"
git ftp push --scope xxxx
```

and you can see what hapens:

```
git ftp show --scope xxxx
git ftp log --scope xxxx
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you really insist on `ftp`, or can you use `rsync` instead?

---

If `ftp` is **required** [mhenry1384's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424680/trying-to-find-a-simple-way-to-do-upload-only-modified-files-through-ftp#424848) is roughly what `rsync` does (well half of it anyway, `rsync` also looks at modification times for files that differ...).

Answer (score 2):

(Waiting for the comment on the main question to be answered before expanding)

The strategy would be:

1. Find the files changed using dates, times, archive bits or hashes (depending on OS)
2. Using this list, generate a FTP script PUTting those files
3. Run the FTP script.

Answer (score 0):

Jonas,

How often are the files likely to change?

If they change on a predictable time frame, you could consider using the modified and other date attributes on the file.

Answer (score 0):

By using [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) it is relatively easy. But it works only if your computer is the only one which modifies the folder on the ftp server...

I heard that rsync is working too, but I am not sure of that, I never used rsync... And it's not ftp...

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans has a nice ftp. it supports selective upload, download