# How to findout if a file has been changed

Tags: file, ftp, synchronization

I need to develop a file synchronization application to sync my files from my local computer to my remote server. My local OS is windows and remote OS is Unix. I can access files on the remote on FTP.

Is file's 'modified date' enough to find out files that has been changed on my computer?

Comment: A lot of applications use the use the [Archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_bit) flag to achieve this effect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424680/trying-to-find-a-simple-way-to-do-upload-only-modified-files-through-ftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, but why reinvent the wheel?

Unison, [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) (for FTP only) or rsync have solved these issues awhile ago.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [`rsync`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), which comes with most Linux distributions, and for which there seems to be a Windows version: http://greenmice.info/en/node/34