# Azure Devops FTP Upload - Upload only changed files on Remote Server

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ftp

The current setup is as below

- Version Control - Git
- Repos and Branch hosted on - Azure DevOps
- Codebase - External server

The dev team clones Azure Repo into local git project and any staged changes are committed via Git and pushed to specific branch of Azure DevOps. In this setup we would want to upload the changes to external FTP servers and avoid manual upload. Currently trying to use Azure Devops FTP Upload Task (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops), and able to successfully run pipeline and publish artifact. However, this script uploads all the files and folders at specified path and not just the staged changed. YAML script as below

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
 - name: StagingRepo
   value: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

steps:

- publish: $(StagingRepo)
  artifact: Staging Repo

- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload'
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: inputs
    serverUrl: 'ftps://00.00.00.00:22'
    username: ftp-username
    password: ftp-password
    rootDirectory: '$(StagingRepo)'
    remoteDirectory: '/home/public_html'
    clean: false
    cleanContents: false
    preservePaths: false
    trustSSL: true
```

**PROBLEM**

Any way that we can only upload only committed changes to FTP instead of uploading the whole repo/files? From the docs, new build pipelines update only the changed files but in this case it is uploading everything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per the task [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops#arguments):
[image]

You are uploading the `whole working directory`(which store your repo content) to remote FTP server.

Please fix `remoteDirectory` as a directory not a file `/home/public_html`.

If you'd like to only upload committed changes to FTP, you need to find the changed files firstly. You can find the yaml script in answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65101831/14996050).

The problem is to upload the files, if you use task "task: FtpUpload@2", you can put the changed files into a folder and upload the `folder content` to remote server, but the changed files will in `same folder` which is different with git repo content.

If you'd to `sync` the change to remote server which means keeping the same file path in repo content, you need to install `git-ftp`. Please refer to the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424680/trying-to-find-a-simple-way-to-do-upload-only-modified-files-through-ftp) and [here](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp). Use git script instead of task to upload the files.

Edit:

This an Extension [FTP Uploader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=januskamphansen.ftpupload-task) which support "Ignore unchanged files".

[image]

Comment: git-ftp works only if your computer is the only one which modifies the folder on the ftp server. While running git-ftp, you have to take care, no one pushes or touches this repo (e.g. no commits, no checkouts, no file modifications). Does this works when you have a team of developers and only one person is not responsible for FTP upload?

Comment: Hi @Slimshadddyyy, I didn't find the notes about the git-ftp limitation, and i find an extension on Azure DevOps: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=januskamphansen.ftpupload-task.

It supports to "Ignore unchanged files", please use it instead for a check.

Comment: Please check the limitations for git-ftp here - https://git-ftp.github.io/.
My understanding is that the marketplace extension won't sync the change to remote server which means keeping the same file path in repo content, just like we do in git push? As you said ` you can put the changed files into a folder and upload the folder content to remote server, but the changed files will in same folder which is different with git repo content.`

Comment: Thanks for the link shared. Could you please check with "FTP Uploader" ?

Comment: Can you share link for "FTP Uploader"?

Comment: Hi @Slimshadddyyy, i have shared the link in the reply: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=januskamphansen.ftpupload-task

Comment: Hi @Slimshadddyyy, does the FTP uploader works for you? Let me know if you have any queries.